# Using and configuring the Rally Git Connector with Atlassian stash

Tags: git, rally, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to set up the Rally Git Connector with Stash. Part of this is to create a config file for rally and git.

Sample config:

```html
VCSConnector:

#
# The content of the file below should follow YAML specifications
# Non standard characters should be enclosed with double quotations
# RepositoryBase is an exception and cannot be enclosed with double quotations
# Therefore the RepositoryBase cannot contain special characters.
#
Rally:
    Server              : "rally.url.com"        # required
    Protocol            : https                       # required, https or (http only for On Premise)
    Username            : "user"          # required
    Password            : "password"               # required, is encoded after first use
    Workspace           : "workspace."          # required, name of Rally Workspace
    RepositoryName      : "GitSCM"                  # required, name of Rally SCMRepository
#   Proxy               : "server:port"               # optional
#   ProxyUser           : "Proxy User"                # optional, use when Proxy is an authenticating proxy
#   ProxyPassword       : "Proxy Password"            # optional, use when Proxy is an authenticating proxy
    Lookback            : 90                          # optional (in minutes), defaults to 60 minutes
    UpdateArtifactState : False                       # False is the default value
    StateExtractorClass : BasicActionsAndArtifactsExtractor(message)  # only used if above is True
    Debug               : False                       # defaults to False, to enable, specify a value of True

Git:
#   Server              : serverurl # optional, but if set connector runner user must authenticate using PKI
    RepositoryBase      : [I DONT KNOW] # required, filesystem path to git repository
    Lookback            : 90                          # in minutes, optional (defaults to 120 minutes)
    MaxItems            : 100                         # required, max items processed in a run
#   RevURI              : "http://git/giturial/bigproject/rev/{revnumber}"             # optional, if running web access to repo
#   FileURI             : "http://git/giturial/bigproject/file/{revnumber}/{filepath}" # optional, if running web access

Services:
    Preview             : True                        # optional; when True, show what would happen
    LogLevel            : Debug                       # optional; default value is Info
#   PostBatchExtension  : MetricsPoster               # for future use

Transforms:                                           # Listing a Transform is Required
    Author              : Passthru                    # Required defaults to Passthru
#   Author              : Blank
#   Author              : EmailAddressAsRallyUser
#   Author              : FileBasedUserNameLookup(user_map.txt, ":")
#   Author              : RallyUserNameLookup(FirstName, LastName)
#   Author              : UserNameDomainAugmentLookup(DomainName)
#   Author              : UserLookupChainGang(FirstName, LastName, user_map.txt, ":")
```

The Rally section  settings I have correct.

The Git section however - I need to add the git RepositoryBase into the config yml file.

I'm not so sure on this part as we are using Atlassian Stash. Where does Stash store this information?

(Everything I'm doing is on the box that stash and the connector is installed onto)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Rally connector requires direct filesystem access and doesn't work with HTTP or SSH based Git hosting, which is what Stash (and frankly, most other tools) offer. You could try pointing the connector to directories inside of Stash, but I have no idea what havoc that might wreak.

There are some alternatives available:

- There is an add-on for Stash that integrates with Rally in the other direction - https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pluginsawesome.stash.plugins.rally-connector
- Someone could mirror Stash repositories to a local filesystem where the Rally connector is running. A mirroring add-on can help automate this - https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.englishtown.stash-hook-mirror

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that may help:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/265978/where-does-stash-store-the-repositories

Comment: I have seen that article but that would indicate that the rally connector can only support a single repository?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  It is one repository per config file.
You can specify multiple config files on one invocation, like:

    ruby  git2rally.rb  cfgfile1  cfgfile2  cfgfile3  cfgfile4

Comment: Can i ask if you have you actually done this? Rally support seem to say that stash isnt compatible with their connector.

Answer (score 0):

Rally Support say that this isn't currently possible with stash data:

> Thank you for contacting Rally Customer Support. I am afraid that Git
>   Stash is not supported since it makes some customizations on
>   repositories which differ from what the connector expects to see.
>
> Our Integrations team has a story in their backlog to develop a
>   connector for Git-Stash specifically. As of right now, this story has
>   not been scheduled nor prioritized, so I cannot specify a time frame
>   on when you should expect this code to be available.
>
> I will be associating your case with the story so you will be notified
>   when it has been developed.
>
> The short term workaround would be to use the Git-VCS connector
>   against a compatible clone of the Git-Stash repository.

So i'll need to clone repos from stash and then set up the connectors to point at those clones repos rather than using stash data directly.